# When working with filters, should you set the context's result always to ContentResult object if you have something you wish to return?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, filter, action-filter

`ContentResult` allows you to specify both the status code you wish to return, as well as the content of your response and its encoding.

Is there any reason to return objects like `OkObjectResult`, `BadRequestObjectResult` etc versus just simply returning a `ContentResult`, provided you actually have content you wish to return (i.e the response has a body, it's not a `NoContentResult` result.)

I'd like to stress out that this is not about opinions on how we should write our code. It's about understanding if returning anything other than `ContentResult` in the above outlined situation offers us any additional benefits, if any at all.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If you developed a WebApi, and used ContentResult everywhere for every
  type of response, you would end up different developers, serializing
  their objects to JSON in different formats at some point. Meaning;
  standardization..
- Those extra methods also prevent code cloning. Imagine you're
  returning HTTP 500 with a JSON content with a code and message to let client know about the servers error and display it. Which is again is best practice for a WebApi design. And you used this 1000 times in your full
  project. Then that means you're calling your Json serializing method 1000 times too while
  you could just not use it at all and leave all that to framework. When time comes, and you decide to switch to a new more optimized library for JSON serializations, you'd end up changing code on 1000 different lines.
- Your code is way more easily testable with these extra result types. You can write unit test rules to tell a test the method should return an OkResult object. Or can write rules over return types.. With always using ContentReult, you'd have to hard code inside your test methods and switch between HTTP Status Code values to decide what to do. That means more IF statements, more lines, means more complexity.

In summary those types are targeted to developers who need them, not to developers who don't need them. So, if you're comfortable using ContentResult only and don't have these concerns, then it's all fine.

Answer (score 3):

If your content is a string, there is no good reason to use a specific object result - in fact it would add overhead that can cost performance. `ObjectResult` is useful for encoding objects to the format requested and thus performs additional operations to check how to serialize the given object.

You can easily see that additional steps are involved when you have a look at the implementation on Github:

[ContentResult](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ContentResult.cs) is just a simple object inheriting directly from ActionResult with some simple-typed properties.

[OkObjectResult](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/OkObjectResult.cs) is a thin layer around ObjectResult that just sets the status code in its constructor.

[ObjectResult](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ObjectResult.cs) has complex types like a collection of output formatters in it that create overhead because they need to be initialized.

Later in the pipeline, `ContentResult` will be handled by the `ContentResultExecutor` and `ObjectResult` will be handled by the `ObjectResultExecutor`.

[ContentResultExecutor](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/b328f501fa1ed6fd61d7f90df05b76e163fbbd7a/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/ContentResultExecutor.cs) is quite simple, it basically just writes the encoded result to the response stream.

[ObjectResultExecutor](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/b328f501fa1ed6fd61d7f90df05b76e163fbbd7a/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/ObjectResultExecutor.cs) isn't that simple, it performs operations like checking the requested output type, determining the type of the given object and serializing the object before writing it to the output stream.

Long story short:
If you just need to return a string, use `ContentResult`. If you need to return a complex object and want to benefit from features like automatically getting the correct output format and performance optimized serialization procedures, use some kind of `ObjectResult`.

Comment: What's stopping me from feeding a serialized object to a `ContentResult` object, and changing the content type to be "application/json"? Wouldn't that be far better than going through everything an `ObjectResult` is doing? I'm not aware what kind of serialization optimizations it has, but I'll be using the `System.Text.Serialization` for json.

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from doing it, I just prefer not duplicating framework functionality just "because I can". Especially stuff like this profits from the experience I expect from the engineers at Microsoft. I didn't dive to deep into the code, but e.g. I expect it to directly write to the response stream and to not pass around an additional serialized string like your approach would do. So your approach will probably also cost additional resources and neglect any performance/memory usage improvement I described in my post, especially with larger objects.

Comment: Another benefit of using this kind of framework-functionality is that everyone using your API can expect all controllers to serialize in a consistent way which can be configured in a central place. Additionally, there are some third-party enhancements like automatic swagger generation that will benefit from your Action having an object returntype instead of `string`